# LF/CR issue with RS232 in Linux

Tags: java, serial-port

I've been having this problem where anytime I send a 0xA through an RS-232 in a Linux OS the receiver interprets that as 2 bytes, 0xD and 0xA. Also whenever I receive 0xD the serial port interprets that as 0xA. I've been reading that there are known issues regarding this, has anybody been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is having this issue I found a work around.

Simply type these commands in the terminal, and the issue went away for me

```
"stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -onclr"
"stty -F /deb/ttyUSB0 -icrnl"
```

/dev/ttyUSB0 can be replaced with whatever file descriptor you are using.

Apparently Linux has these settings set by default. (I don't why)